# Почему авторизация wordpress работает частично?

Tags: php, wordpress, авторизация

Доброе время суток.
Сайт на Wordpress с самописной темой имеет форму авторизации https://allbriz.ru/login/
На ней введя почту и пароль после отработки wp_signon пользователь переадресовывается на главную страницу.
**И вот тут начинаются чудеса!**
 Функция is_user_logged_in на главной странице и странице авторизации https://allbriz.ru/login/ вернёт `false`, а на любой другой `true`.
Так же авторизация нормально срабатывает если обновить главную страницу F5 и в InternetExplorer и если сделать переадресацию с каким либо GET параметром, к примеру `https://allbriz.ru/?login=true`.
Ну и само собой на `https://allbriz.ru/wp-login.php` так же всё отрабатывает на Ура!

Comment: Может кэширование на сервере криво настроено?

Comment: Да, так и оказалось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После тщательного анализа выяснилось, что проблема возникла после добавления инструкций в файл .htaccess

> ```
> # сжатие text, html, javascript, css, xml:
> <ifModule mod_deflate.c>
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript
> ```
>
> application/javascript application/x-javascript
>
> ```
> # кеш браузера
> <ifModule mod_expires.c>
> ExpiresActive On
>
> #по умолчанию кеш в 5 секунд
> ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days"
>
> # Включаем кэширование изображений и флэш на месяц
> ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
> ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 4 weeks"
> ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 30 days"
> ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 43829 minutes"
> ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
>
> # Включаем кэширование css, javascript и текстовых файлов на одну неделю
> ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
> ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
> ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
> ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
>
> # Включаем кэширование html и htm файлов на один день
> ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 43200 seconds"
>
> # Включаем кэширование xml файлов на десять минут
> ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
> ```

решили оставить редирект с GET параметром ?login=true